# Do I have to redownload MNIST with fetch_openml every time I run my Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, dataset, mnist

Everything's in the title.
I run the following code in my notebook:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
```

But do I have to refetch the dataset every single time I reopen my Notebook?
Is there a way to store the dataset locally?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Scikit-learn` fetchers have param `data_home`, which you can specify. It's default is `None`. In this case data is stored in `~/scikit_learn_data` subfolder. For more params see `fetch_openml?`